# Remove CUDA 10.0 and install CUDA 9.2 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install TensorFlow-gpu, so I need the CUDA toolkit 9.2.
Unfortunately I installed CUDA 10 and then realized that.

How can I easily remove CUDA 10.0 and install CUDA 9.2, without touching the drivers (since I have Ubuntu 18 I would like to maintain the latest video drivers)?

- I already tried to simple install CUDA 9.2 from .deb (network) file, it says

> dpkg: error processing archive cuda-repo-ubuntu1710_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb (--install):
>
> trying to overwrite '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list', which is also in package cuda-repo-ubuntu1804 10.0.130-1

- I already tried to simple install CUDA 9.2 from .run file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028830/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04), it says

> Not enough space on parition mounted at /tmp.
>   Need 2895511552 bytes.
>
> Disk space check has failed. Installation cannot continue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue as follow :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda-10.0
```

This will remove `cuda-10.0` and then you can install `cuda-9.2` as you want

Answer (score 1):

+1 to installing a stand-alone CUDA-9.2 in a separate dir using `.run` installer. That should work.

You can specify an alternative location for the temporary files using `--tmpdir=...` option when you run the `.run` installer.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem using @Cs20 answer and doing:

`sudo dpkg -P <package name>`

in this case `<package name>` is cuda-repo-ubuntu1804